Как реализовать аутентификацию с помощью Next.js и Express: хранение JWT и подписанные cookies?
На данный момент я разрабатываю приложение на основе Next.js с и Express, и столкнулся с вопросом: как лучше реализовать хранение токенов аутентификации и их безопасную проверку? Я храню JWT(JWS) токен в cookies для express и хочу отдельно хранить подписанные cookies для next, JWT проверять в expresse а cookies в сервере next . Есть ли другие варианты? и насколько безопасно этот вариант?

Тут глобально 2 варианта:

Установить HttpOnly на cookie, дабы если попробовать через js пробраться, ничего не вышло.
И на стороне сервера использовать middleware или API маршруты, чтобы проверять JWT.


На StackOverflow редко отвечают на подобные вопросы. Тут прошу прощения, по-идеи, даже у меня будет downvote

я это сделал но не могу решить хранить ещё и токен или подписанное cookie на next чтобы и там поверять перед отправкой запроса на express ещё и некоторые части ui/ux будут зависеть               залогинен пользователь или нет, или использовать один токен для всех, и какой безопаснее подписаны cookies или jwt, ещё и придётся синхронизировать их время действий

Если UI/UX зависит от статуса пользователя, лучше использовать JWT, так как он легко интегрируется с клиентом. Но опять-таки подписанные cookies гораздо безопаснее, если вы правда сделали выше сказанное.
